# Magento2: Append URL with size and color value in Configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I have configurable product.
I want append URL once I click on configurable option with query string on the product detail page. Like,
.html?size=XL&color=red
And also once it append in the URL and If we try to Reload page then  selected parameter will be selected after page load.

Here what I did. I am not sure is this proper flow for this requirement Or not.

```
_OnClick: function ($this, $widget, eventName) {
        var $parent = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass),
            $wrapper = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeOptionsWrapper),
            $label = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeSelectedOptionLabelClass),
            attributeId = $parent.attr('attribute-id'),
            $input = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput);

        var color = $label.html();
        var size = $this.html();

        window.location.hash = '?size='+size+'&color='+color;
```

Comment: Are you using swatch or dropdown?

Comment: I am using swatches

Comment: Can you update what you have done?

Comment: I am working in swatch-renderer.js on _OnClick: function ($this, $widget, eventName) { function.  var color = $label.html(); var size = $this.html(); window.location.hash = '?size='+size+'&color='+color; but it's not working properly. Can you please give your code in answer.

Comment: Can you update the _onClick function to your question?

Comment: Updated what I did. But I think I did wrong can you please give your code snippet to get this done. Thanks in adv.

Comment: Wait I am checking. I ll update you with my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code for _OnClick function:

```
_OnClick: function ($this, $widget, eventName) {
    var $parent = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass),
        $wrapper = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeOptionsWrapper),
        $label = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeSelectedOptionLabelClass),
        attributeId = $parent.attr('attribute-id'),
        $input = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput);



        //console.log($parent);

        //window.location.hash = '?size='+size+'&color='+color;

    if ($widget.inProductList) {
        $input = $widget.productForm.find(
            '.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput + '[name="super_attribute[' + attributeId + ']"]'
        );
    }

    if ($this.hasClass('disabled')) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        $parent.removeAttr('option-selected').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $input.val('');
        $label.text('');
        $this.attr('aria-checked', false);
    } else {
        $parent.attr('option-selected', $this.attr('option-id')).find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $label.text($this.attr('option-label'));
        $input.val($this.attr('option-id'));
        $input.attr('data-attr-name', this._getAttributeCodeById(attributeId));
        $this.addClass('selected');
        $widget._toggleCheckedAttributes($this, $wrapper);
    }

    $widget._Rebuild();

    if ($widget.element.parents($widget.options.selectorProduct)
            .find(this.options.selectorProductPrice).is(':data(mage-priceBox)')
    ) {
        $widget._UpdatePrice();
    }

    $widget._loadMedia(eventName);
    $input.trigger('change');
    var i =0;
    var hashUrl = '';
    $('.swatch-attribute[option-selected]').each(function(index){
        if(i > 0) hashUrl+= '&';
        hashUrl+=$(this).attr('attribute-code')+'='+$(this).attr('option-selected');
        i++;
    });
    if(hashUrl) window.location.hash = '?'+hashUrl;
},
```

Magento2 already have an option to select it by attribute code and option Id. You can also see the function **_EmulateSelected** where it triggers click for each selected options.

You can also check the function **_EmulateSelected** from where it check the parameters from the url and return the selected options with attribute code to the function **_RenderControls**. In the function **_RenderControls** you can find the line `$widget._EmulateSelected($widget._getSelectedAttributes());` at the end of the function which tells that options are selected.

The code is not tested but it should works.

Comment: Thank You so much for help. Can you please add code for append label instead of value. hashUrl+=$(this).attr('attribute-code')+'='+$i need lable here;

Comment: Dont use label as if you check their code they have read attribute code instead of label and option id instead of label. Thats why I have added this only and it works.

Comment: Thank You it help me, Yes it's magento default they read attribute code. But here I need crack that and apply our customisation to read label. I am working here _getSelectedAttributes: function () { but still not get what I want.

Comment: Done............

Comment: Hi Sukumar Gorai, Your code works fine when i refresh the same category page. But in my case I want the size URL gets appended when  the page gets refresh as well as when i go to the different category then also i need  the previous size URL to get append. Please help me. Thanks in advance.